# Avoiding 'Layer exceeds max dimensions supported by the GPU in Android

Tags: java, android

So in my app I have two activities, and when the second one is launched, JSON data such as text and images gets displayed there.

The problem is, I can't know how long the text will bee so i get that error.

Is there any work around it? I can't release app like that on Google Play!

Here's my log:

```
07-29 14:50:27.380 29205-29253/com.example.dario.upmovies W/OpenGLRenderer: Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU (1080x4531, max=4096x4096)
07-29 14:50:27.381 29205-29253/com.example.dario.upmovies D/OpenGLRenderer: Current memory usage / total memory usage (bytes):
                                                                              TextureCache         16284072 / 50331648
                                                                              LayerCache                  0 / 33554432 (numLayers = 0)
                                                                                Layer size 1088x704; isTextureLayer()=0; texid=44 fbo=9; refs=2
                                                                              Layers total    3063808 (numLayers = 1)
                                                                              RenderBufferCache           0 /  4194304
                                                                              GradientCache           16384 /  1048576
                                                                              PathCache                3700 / 25165824
                                                                              TessellationCache       24552 /  1048576
                                                                              TextDropShadowCache         0 /  5242880
                                                                              PatchCache                  0 /   131072
                                                                              FontRenderer 0 A8      524288 /   524288
                                                                              FontRenderer 0 RGBA         0 /        0
                                                                              FontRenderer 0 total   524288 /   524288
                                                                            Other:
                                                                              FboCache                    0 /        0
                                                                            Total memory usage:
                                                                              19916804 bytes, 18.99 MB
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallStaticVoidMethodV called with pending exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' thrown in void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int):-2
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to CallStaticVoidMethodV
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x738ff000 self=0xb4827800
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=29205 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fc1bec
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 2713918368 2160510665 6901 ) utm=240 stm=31 core=0 HZ=100
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xbe3d0000-0xbe3d2000 stackSize=8MB
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 0000484c  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00003031  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 0024359b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*, BacktraceMap*)+70)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 002279e3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, BacktraceMap*) const+154)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000affdd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+584)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b0725  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+60)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b3867  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::ScopedCheck(_JNIEnv*, int, char const*)+1286)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000bafe3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+30)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 0005be7b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 0007b8ef  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 0007925d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #11 pc 000796cb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #12 pc 00011055  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+408)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #13 pc 00011149  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #14 pc 0007dd49  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #15 pc 000b5be3  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+102)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:195)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
07-29 14:50:27.480 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] 
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294] Runtime aborting...
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294] Aborting thread:
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x738ff000 self=0xb4827800
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   | sysTid=29205 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fc1bec
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   | state=R schedstat=( 2738514980 2164556658 6950 ) utm=241 stm=32 core=3 HZ=100
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   | stack=0xbe3d0000-0xbe3d2000 stackSize=8MB
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #00 pc 0000484c  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #01 pc 00003031  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #02 pc 0024359b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*, BacktraceMap*)+70)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #03 pc 002279e3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, BacktraceMap*) const+154)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #04 pc 00218605  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*)+24)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #05 pc 0021897b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+634)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #06 pc 00218b5d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+72)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #07 pc 000a64bb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1322)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #08 pc 000b01cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1078)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #09 pc 000b0725  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+60)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #10 pc 000b3867  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::ScopedCheck(_JNIEnv*, int, char const*)+1286)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #11 pc 000bafe3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+30)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #12 pc 0005be7b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #13 pc 0007b8ef  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #14 pc 0007925d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #15 pc 000796cb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #16 pc 00011055  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+408)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #17 pc 00011149  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #18 pc 0007dd49  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   native: #19 pc 000b5be3  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+102)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:195)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294] Pending exception java.lang.IllegalStateException thrown by 'void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int):-2'
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for LinearLayout
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int) (MessageQueue.java:-2)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:143)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:195)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:5389)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[], boolean) (Method.java:-2)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:372)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1020)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:815)
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
07-29 14:50:27.511 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:294] 
07-29 14:50:27.512 29205-29205/com.example.dario.upmovies A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 29205 (.dario.upmovies)
```

Comment: I'm also dealng with this error. My searching has lead me to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37039824 
In my case the issue occurred on a particular TextView with a long text in it and when the device font size is set too large - I am still looking for a fix...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with the following code

```
val t = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
t.replace(R.id.main_fl, fragment)
t.setReorderingAllowed(true) ----> remove this
t.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE) ----> remove this
```

so by removeing set treasition and set recoding allowed ,I solved the problem , I think the problem was when moveing from a complex UI fragment to another complex UI fragment and also saving the instance of both fragment (i'm saving the fragments in the activity) and also using an animation when replacing cause this problem

In you case I think you are trying to an animation some where this a complex UI